# RxJava2 dispose() doesn't work if called on the object returned by doOnSubscribe()

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I've got a problem with understanding why the following code doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or is it some kind of bug in RxJava2 implementation?

```
private Disposable savedDisposable;

@Test
public void test() {
    final TestObserver<Integer> observer = new TestObserver<>();

    Observable<Integer> t = Observable.just(10)
            .delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> savedDisposable = disposable);

    t.subscribe(observer);

    savedDisposable.dispose();  //this doesn't work
    //observer.dispose();       //this works  

    assertTrue(observer.isDisposed());
}
```

Comment: By not working I assume assertTrue fails?

Comment: @James yes, exactly

Comment: Please avoid cross posting: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5299

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer the posted question:

You are disposing in the middle thus the end `Disposable` can't know about its upstream has been disposed because `dispose()` calls always travel upstream.

There are the `DisposableObserver`, `ResourceObserver`, `subscribeWith` and the lambda-`subscribe()` methods that will get you a `Disposable` object at the very end which you can dispose via `dispose()`.

---

On the issue list though, it turned out the OP wanted an `Observer` and `Disposable` to be present on the consumer type and discovered that this can be achieved via constrained generics, for example:

```
public static <T, K extends Observer<T> & Disposable> K subscribe(
        Observable<T> o, K observer) {
    o.subscribe(observer);
    return observer;
}
```

Comment: What is a valid use case for the disposable provided by `doOnSubscribe()`? It seems like the official documentation and myriad of assorted tutorials don't sufficiently stress that using `doOnSubscribe()` to acquire a `Disposable` for a subscription should be avoided.  

Thanks for the clarification.  I have a lot of code that needs to be reviewed!